# How to capture 4 screenshots and to specify time for everyone

Tags: ffmpeg

How to capture 4 screenshots in one inquiry, specifying time for each of screenshots?

For example:

```
The 1st screenshot on 00:01:19 min.
The 2nd screenshot on 00:01:36 min.
The 3rd screenshot on 00:03:05 min.
The 4th screenshot on 00:05:51 min.
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could supply some more information. What is your operating system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 4 images from 4 different times (lazy way)

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:19 -i input -vframes 1 output_01.png
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:36 -i input -vframes 1 output_02.png
ffmpeg -ss 00:03:05 -i input -vframes 1 output_03.png
ffmpeg -ss 00:05:51 -i input -vframes 1 output_04.png
```

- Alternatively, `-ss` can accept a value in seconds, such as `-ss 79`.

## 4 images from 4 different times (one command)

```
ffmpeg \
-ss 00:01:19 -i input \
-ss 00:01:36 -i input \
-ss 00:03:05 -i input \
-ss 00:05:51 -i input \
-map 0:v -vframes 1 output_01.png \
-map 1:v -vframes 1 output_02.png \
-map 2:v -vframes 1 output_03.png \
-map 3:v -vframes 1 output_04.png
```

## Using [select filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) (possibly slow)

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "select=eq(t\,79)+eq(t\,96)+eq(t\,185)+eq(t\,60*5+51)" \
-vsync vfr output_%02d.png
```

- `-vsync vfr` is added to prevent duplicates from being outputted.

## Also see

- [FFmpeg image file muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2)
- [`-ss` option documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: Seeking](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking)

Comment: Why is there a vsync in the last option?

Comment: @jiggunjer Otherwise select will output each following frame as a duplicate until the next timestamp, so instead of 4 images it would end up with 4 sets of numerous duplicates. I will add that to the answer.

Comment: I try to start on the server (Apache + PHP + ffmpeg): `$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg \ -ss 00:01:19 -i ' . $videoPath . ' \ -ss 00:01:36 -i ' . $videoPath . ' \ -ss 00:03:05 -i ' . $videoPath . ' \ -ss 00:05:51 -i ' . $videoPath . ' \ -map 0:v -vframes 1 output_01.png \ -map 1:v -vframes 1 output_02.png \ -map 2:v -vframes 1 output_03.png \ -map 3:v -vframes 1 output_04.png 2>&1');
`   Gives a mistake:  `[NULL @ 0x7853a0] Unable to find a suitable output format for ' -ss'
 -ss: Invalid argument`

Comment: If i remove some space `\ -ss` ==> `\-ss` I receive a mistake: `Error while opening encoder for output stream #2:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height`

Comment: @Plush Does it work if you run `ffmpeg` manually, unscripted in command-line interface?

Comment: I can't start manually (restriction of a hosting), I can add that capturing a single screenshot works — `ffmpeg -ss 00:01:19 -i input -map 0:v -vframes 1 output_01.png`

Comment: @Plush The "one command" example works for me in cli. Probably a problem with your script and not the `ffmpeg` command, but that is a separate issue.

Comment: The error can be to depend on the ffmpeg version? What version at you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33537/discussion-between-lordneckbeard-and-plush).

Comment: There is a difference meanwhile how to specify a video stream: `- map 0:v` or `- map:v 0`, it influences work?

Comment: @Plush See http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map and http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options